# Trigonometry inside a trapezium

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

[image]

I have the following image, and it's asked to find the values of $X$ and $Y$.

I've managed to find it using the this idea: Divide the image in two right triangles and let's call the height of the trapezium $H$.

The opposite cathetus of the left triangle has a length of $\frac{H}{\tan{60^{\circ}}}$ and the opposite cathetus of the right triangle is $\frac{H}{\tan{30^{\circ}}}$.

The sum of this two catheti has to be equals to $12$, in this sum, we can assume that the height $H = 3\sqrt{3}$.

Applying trigonometrical functions in both triangles, I managed to find that $X = 6, Y = 6\sqrt{3}$

But a friend of mine has found $X = 8, Y = \frac{16\sqrt{3}}{3}$, and he did it in a completely different manner from mine.

Which one is right ?

Comment: please share his/her "completely different manner"

Comment: He didn't shared with me the full idea, but he claims it's right, the only clue he gave is that he didn't cared for the trapezium height.

Comment: I've posted an answer that I think is simpler than the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the left right-angled triangle's lower left $\;x\;$,  so that $\;X=2x\;,\;\;H=\sqrt3x\;$, and thus in the right right-angled triangle we have that the lower leg is $\;3x\;$, and its hypotenuse is $\;2\sqrt3 x\;$.

Adding both lower legs above we get

$$x+3x=4x=12\implies x=3\implies \begin{cases}X=6\\{}\\Y=2\sqrt3\cdot3=6\sqrt3\end{cases}$$

and the above only uses basic Euclidean geometry.

Comment: I didn't understand your relations with 'left-angled triangles lower left x'. Could you be more specific ?

Comment: @aajjbb In a $\;30-60-90\;$ triangle, the length of the leg in front of the $\;30^\circ\;$ angle is half the hypotenuse's, and from here (and Pythagoras Theorem, of course) all the relations...:)

Comment: Great, also, could you please point where do I make a mistake in my approach ?

Comment: I'm not sure: you begin with "the opposite cathetus"...opposite to **what** ? You *must* give an angle...

Comment: In the right side triangle, opposite to 60 angle and in the left side triangle, opposite to 30.

Comment: Let us take the left triangle: $$\sqrt3=\tan 60=H/x\implies x=H/\sqrt3$$ and the last one is the length of the side opposite to the $\;30^\circ\;$ angle...in the left triangle, of course!

Comment: Likewise, in the right triangle the horizontal leg is $\;\sqrt3\, H\;$ , and together $$\frac4{\sqrt3}H=12\implies H=3\sqrt3$$

Comment: @aajjbb Maybe I forgot to tell you: you don't make any mistake, your results are right. You asked about not caring for the height of the trapezium, and I showed you how to do that.

Comment: @aajjbb, please do check my editing. I wrote $\;4x=12\implies x=4\;$...since my graduate studies my arithmetic sucks. It must, of course, be $\;x=3\implies X=2x=6\;$ and etc., and thus your result is correct...and we don't need to know the height, so it is trivial to deduce it.

Answer (score 3):

After the construction of the red parallel line, the problem becomes more easy to solve.
 [image]

Comment: Nice answer!, but its beauty becomes distorted by that diagram. Why don't you use GeoGebra?

Comment: Yes, I probably have some kind of mental block, the upper angle really doesn't seems to be a right angle (although I know it has), so I can't imagine of a real right angle, sorry for it :(

Comment: @Sawarnik The diagram is not that bad, especially for one who is not that familiar with GeoGebra. However, I will spend some time in learning it. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to create three right triangles: two of the inside the trapezium, and one outside.

the two inside will be created by drawing two lines down from and perpendicular to the top 8 cm leg. This will give you two right triangles with a rectangle between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do without finding H. Let $B$ and $b$ be the two bases of the trapezium. Then $$\frac 1 2 X+\frac {\sqrt 3}{2}Y=B-b \\\frac{\sqrt 3} 2 X = \frac 1{2}Y.$$ Surely you can solve this system.

Comment: I can't understand the relation you use with B - b in the first equation.

Comment: $X\cos(60°)+Y\cos(30°)=B-b.$

Answer (score 0):

If you just cut out eight centimeters from the top and from the bottom, then you have a $30^\circ{-}60^\circ{-}90^\circ$ triangle whose hypotenuse has length 12 centimeters.  Its shorter leg must therefore have length 6 centimeters, and then the other leg can be found via Pythagoras.